# using a spinner to change values

Tags: java, android, arrays, timer

So I have three different arrays of values, At runtime I want to use one of these arrays. The arrays hold ints which stand for a time value. So the time changes each time A value of the spinner is selected. To make it more clear I have

```
int[] time1={4,3,5,2,5}
int[] time2={9,4,3,5,2,6,3,7}
int[] time3={4.5.2.1.6,6}
```

The reason I do this is because I want my countDownTimer to use a different value the button is clicked. On the GUi side I want to have a spinner that has three different options time1, time2, time3. I am confused about if I should be using a spinner or radioButtons. I want only one of them to be selected at a time, and I want the array to change at runtime so there is no need to exit the program and reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use radio buttons to select which spinner is to be used. Enable and disable the appropriate spinner.

```
spinner1.setEnabled(false);
spinner2.setEnabled(true);
spinner3.setEnabled(false);
```

You could also set the:

```
spinner.isClickable(boolean);
```

There are methods to set the background color, visibility and transparency that you could use to indicate that which spinner is enabled. You also may want to think about using 1 spinner with 3 radio buttons and dynamically change the spinner values based on which radio button is selected.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Great Thank you! For my purpose the only thing riding off of the spinner is an array, so it isn't necessary to make the radio buttons but, I do see where you're going with that and I will be sure to test out how to do that! Thank you!